# Using R to match image subset with larger image

Tags: r, image-processing

I am using R for some very simple image analysis. Specifically, I'm trying to determine if one image is a cropped version of another image.

There has got to be a "simple" way to do this in R - but I'm not finding it. I suspect I'm over-thinking the problem - so looking for guidance on what I'm missing.

Specifically, consider the following:

```
install.packages("jpeg")
library(jpeg)

image.main <- readJPEG("path to a jpeg image")
image.main.sub <- readJPEG("path to another jpeg image, cropped version of the first")

if (someMagicFunctionThatFindsSubImage(image.main,image.main.sub)) {
    # TRUE - image.main.sub is a subset of image.main 
} else {
    # FALSE - image.main.sub is NOT a subset of image.main
}

someMagicFunctionThatFindsSubImage <- function (bigImage,smallImage) {
  # the matrix of values that represent smallImage is also present
  # in the matrix of values that represent bigImage
  # bigImage and smallImage can be megabytes in size
  # bigImage and smallImage can be limited to RGB Jpeg data (array of X,Y and 3 layers)
}
```

I've tried:

- grep, grepl, grepRaw : error - pattern has length > 1
- package rimage: error, package ‘rimage’ is not available
- package raster: not sure how to use this to find image subsets (am I overthinking this?)
- package ripa: likewise, not sure how to use this (again, am I overthinking this?)

I've been collecting results at [this github](https://github.com/mnr/CodeClinicR/tree/master/2_CodeClinic_ImageAnalysis) and will keep it updated.

THANK YOU

mnr

Comment: Please edit your question to address 2 questions: What is the meaning of "image subset"? AND what package is readJPEG from?

Comment: Why do you think this is an "easy" task with **any** software?  If you are dead certain there'll never be recompression, bit depths, etc., then you *could* use the small image as a kernal in a convolution operation.  That's processor-intensive to say the least;  good matching algorithms often cost money, with reason.

Comment: @BondedDust : added install.packages("jpeg") and library(jpeg).

Comment: @CarlWitthoft : Granted - image analysis is difficult. But before I jump to the complex, I'm trying to make sure I've exhausted the simple. "Programming is the art of avoiding complex solutions"

Comment: While you're at it, please do not use "complex" for "complicated."  Complex numbers are a very specific concept in math and thus in software as well.

Comment: Anyway,  there are "blob-matching" algorithms out there which you might be able to adapt to your needs.  Take a peek at `imageJ` from NIH  http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/ just in case.

Comment: sorry. s/complex/complicated/g . my bad.

Answer (score 8):

Actually, it turns out there ***is*** an "easy" way to do this. I was fortunate to spend Christmas with a Professor in Image Analysis. It took him upwards of one minute to suggest using **cross-covariance** or **cross-correlation**. Both are present in R as part of the stats package.

```
>? ccf
```

Here's how it works:

In my example above, I import a JPEG image using...

```
> install.packages("jpeg")
> library(jpeg)

> image.main <- readJPEG("path to a jpeg image")
> image.main.sub <- readJPEG("path to another jpeg image, cropped version of the first")
```

This loads image.main and image.main.sub with the contents of the jpeg image - something like this...

```
> str(image.main)
num [1:3456, 1:5184, 1:3] 0.839 0.839 0.827 0.831 0.835 ..
```

For the sake of this discussion, I'm going to create a highly simplified version of this data. Bear with me for a second...

```
> image.main <- sample(1:20,20)
> image.main.sub <- image.main[5:8]
```

Imagine image.main contains a very small jpeg image.

image.main.sub contains a subset of image.main.

They look like this...

```
> image.main
[1]  2 10  8  9 19  5 11  3  7 16 20 15  6 14 17  1 13 18 12  4
> image.main.sub
[1] 19  5 11  3
```

Now, we can determine where image.main.sub is located within image.main with the ccf function

```
> ccf(image.main,image.main.sub,plot=FALSE)

Autocorrelations of series ‘X’, by lag

   -3     -2     -1      0      1      2      3 
0.440 -0.332  0.295 -0.935  0.327 -0.010  0.215
```

ccf shows the [correlation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_and_dependence) between the two data sets at different offsets (lags). A value of 1 indicates a 100% correlation. Observe the result if we subset image.main to match image.main.sub...

```
> ccf(image.main[5:8],image.main.sub,plot=FALSE)

Autocorrelations of series ‘X’, by lag

    -3     -2     -1      0      1      2      3 
-0.398  0.281 -0.382  1.000 -0.382  0.281 -0.398
```

Note the value of 1.000 at a lag of 0. A match!

Related to this procedure is [template matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_matching).

I've built out the entire solution at my [github](https://github.com/mnr/CodeClinicR/tree/master/2_CodeClinic_ImageAnalysis) page.

mnr

Comment: just a small fyi: The github link does not seem up to date,...